# Why Cant I Sculpt Together These Joined Pieces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I'm in the middle of making my own game and right now and I'm trying to make a model for my main character(A Cat). But it seems I can't get this ear to work properly? Whenever I try to use the sculpting tool to join the two meshes together, I can't. No matter the brush they just don't want to touch each other. That makes no sense to me, they are joined, aren't they? I grabbed them all and used Ctrl + J, so why aren't they acting like one single object? Did I do something wrong?[image: Model In Editor]

Comment: can u upload ur blend file?

Comment: You'll need to remesh them first, so the seperate meshes will be merged. (Look at the top right of the 3D view, where it says "Remesh".

Answer (score 0):

They have been joined so they exist under the same mesh data block, but it looks like they are still separate islands.  Sculpting works on one island of verts that is a closed shape.

You could perhaps separate them back out, move them such that they intersect just a bit and run a union boolean on them.